# Splicing an array to add an item at a specific index

Tags: php, splice

```
$add = array_splice($fileArr1, $addWhere, 1, $addSong);
```

I have been working on a project for a while that adds a song name into a specific place in an array based on variables in a form. I'm really confused, and can provide extra code if that will help with solving my problem. Thank you.

```
<form method="post" action="addtlogan9573.php">
<p><label for="addSong">Add what song? </label><input type="text" name="addSong" id="addSong" /></p>
<p><label for="addWhere">Add where? </label><input type="text" name="addWhere" id="addWhere" /></p>
```

Here is the entirety of my code as is.

```
<?php

$fileName = "tunes.txt"; 
$fileString = file_get_contents($fileName);
$fileArr = explode("|", $fileString); 
$fileArr1 = array_values($fileArr); 
array_unshift($fileArr1, ' '); 
unset($fileArr1[0]);


if (!$_POST) { 

?>

<form method="post" action="addtlogan9573.php">
<p><label for="addSong">Add what song? </label><input type="text" name="addSong" id="addSong" /></p>
<p><label for="addWhere">Add where? </label><input type="text" name="addWhere" id="addWhere" /></p>
<input class="MyButton" type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


<?php
}
else {


    print "<pre>";
$addSong = $_POST['addSong']; 
$addWhere = $_POST['addWhere'];
$add = array_splice($fileArr1, $addWhere, 1, $addSong);
foreach ($add as $key => $val){
print "$key. $val\n";
}
print "</pre>";

$append=implode("|", $fileArr1); 
file_put_contents("backups/".microtime("tunes.txt"), $append); 

include("inc_navigationtlogan9573.php"); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array and create a new array:

```
if ($_POST['formSubmit']) {  
   $newArr = array();
   $addWhere = $_POST['addWhere'];
   $addSong = $_POST['addSong'];

   $cnt = 0;
  foreach($fileArr1 as $file) {
    if ($cnt == $addWhere) {
        $newArr[] = $addSong;
        $newArr[] = $file;
    } else {
        $newArr[] = $file;
    }
    $cnt++;
  }
}
```

$newArr is the final array of songs. You will need to make sure you have the following as your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

This is your code, only it works.

```
<?php

  $fileName = "tunes.txt"; 
  $fileString = file_get_contents($fileName);
  $fileArr = explode("|", $fileString); 
  $fileArr1 = array_values($fileArr); 
  array_unshift($fileArr1, ' '); 
  unset($fileArr1[0]);

?>

<form method="post" action="addtlogan9573.php">
  <p><label for="addSong">Add what song? </label><input type="text" name="addSong" id="addSong" /></p>
  <p><label for="addWhere">Add where? </label><input type="text" name="addWhere" id="addWhere" /></p>
  <input class="MyButton" type="submit" name="formSubmit" />
</form>


<?php

  if ($_POST['formSubmit']) {
     $newArr = array();
   $addWhere = $_POST['addWhere'];
   $addSong = $_POST['addSong'];

   $cnt = 0;
  foreach($fileArr1 as $file) {
    if ($cnt == $addWhere) {
        $newArr[] = $addSong;
        $newArr[] = $file;
    } else {
        $newArr[] = $file;
    }
    $cnt++;
  }
}

  $append=implode("|", $fileArr1); 
  file_put_contents("backups/".microtime("tunes.txt"), $append); 

  include("inc_navigationtlogan9573.php"); 

?>
```

Using this:

```
if (!$_POST)
```

won't work. You need to reference a specific post variable name. You will use '$newArr' as the correct array of songs.

Comment: The variables addWhere and addSong are what the users input into the form, that didn't really work.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The addSong variable is an audio file. And I'm assuming the addWhere variable is where in the array to add the song?

Comment: It's not an audio file though, it's just a list of songs. And the user is just supposed to be able to add the song and see it in the array when the form is submitted.

Comment: Oh ok, so the addSong variable is an array of songs? So, if the user is going to be able to manipulate the array on the front end, why are you trying to put it in the array on the back end? If the user can set the new song where they please, the data will come over in order.

Comment: The addSong variable is the name of the song the user wants to add. I can edit more code in if you need to see the form that I'm using with it?

Comment: Yes, if I could see the form being submitted, that would help clear up the confusion.

Comment: Edited into the question.

Comment: Ok, but you said addSong was a list of files, is that the case? They are just separated by commas by the user?

Comment: The array of songs is fileArr1, the addSong is whatever the user decides to input as a song into the form, and addWhere is the index they want to add the song to within the array.

Comment: That's exactly what my original answer does.

Comment: addWhere is an integer, it just shows up blank when I try submitting the form using the code you provided.

Comment: None of the code I provided is for submitting the form. It's for manipulating the data gathered from the form. I'll update it to grab the values from the form but I thought you were already doing that somewhere above.

Comment: How are you submitting your form? Because that's how you grab post variables in PHP. The other code works because I just tested it. What's the exact issue? Because that code grabs the form data and generates a new array. I've tested both of those things on the code in my answer and they both work.

Comment: It's an all in one form if that makes any difference, but I'm using post for the form method.

Comment: I assumed it's all in one form. You can only submit one post form at a time. And I saw in your form you were using the post method. That's why I added $_POST['addSong'] and $_POST['addWhere'] to get that data. So, whats not working? You haven't told me exactly what isn't working.

Comment: Okay, so when I use my code, a song will show, but it's a song that's already in the list. But when I used yours, it ends up just being a blank page showing nothing. So I'm not really sure what is wrong. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: How does a song show up? Nothing in your code performs that functionality. Sounds like you are running the php code before the form is submitted. Which is incorrect. Once the form is submitted, that is when that php code needs to be ran. If it's ran before the form is submitted you have to add an if statement to it to make sure it only gets executed if the post form has been submitted. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Still not working, I must just have something simple wrong with my code.

Comment: You need to provide all of your code. Something is missing. Because you haven't provided the entire html form. And the issue is not with the php code in my answer. Provide the rest of your code.

Comment: That html is completely different than the form provided in your original post. Of course my php code isn't going to work with that because I wrote it based on your original form provided in your question. You need to be much more thorough in providing all the correct information needed to answer the question upfront.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: formSubmit on line 49, got that error now. Trying to fix.

Comment: Add a print_r($_POST);  It will print a blank array first, but once you submit the form it should print everything being sent in the post request.

Comment: "Array ( [addSong] => Potatos [addWhere] => 1 [formSubmit] => Submit )" That shows, but it should show the whole original array with the song the user wanted to add.

Comment: You aren't passing the original array through the form. It won't show up in the post data. You are defining it at the top in your php code, not in your form.

Comment: The top php code defines the original array, the form gathers the song and position the user wants to add, and the bottom php code creates the final array of songs. If you know where to go from here, accept my answer.